# Taylor Polynomial Approximtions

Tags: taylor-expansion

Answer Provided. Explanation needed.

Hi,

I am asked to construct a Taylor polynomial approximation that is accurate to within $10^{-3}$ over the indicated interval using $x_0=0$ with the following

$$f(x) = \sin(x), x \in [0,\pi]$$

Answer:

The remainder here is:

$$R_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\cos(c)$$

Question: Where does this $R_n(x)$ come from? Why are we multiplying by $\cos(c)$?

for $c\in[0,\pi]$. Therefore, we have

$$|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}|\pi|^{2n+1}\leq \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Question: Where does $\pi^{2n+1}$ come from? Are we substituting $\pi$ and $c$ due to the interval in some way?

We know that the Taylor series expansion for $\sin(x)$ is

$$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$

Why is this different by the alternating sign compared to $R_n(x)$ (above)?

$$\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}|R_6(x)| \leq .466e - 3$$
but
$$\max_{x\in[0,\pi]}|R_5(x)| \leq .737e - 2$$

Question: What is the $\max$ function and why is this necessary?

Therefore the required Taylor polynomial is

$$p_{11}(x) = 1 - x + \frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \frac{x^9}{9!} + \frac{x^{11}}{11!}$$

Comment: What value of $c$ gives you the max for $\cos c$? This value of $c$ can be used for max of $x$ in $|x^{2n+1}|$ The max function is trying to bound what the maximum error can be. It does not mean exact error, just a way to bound the max error. $R_n$ is the Taylor Remainder, which you can find on the Wiki or any calc book, for example see http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf

Comment: I have looked at that reference too. It does not explicity state that $\cos(c)$ must be multiplied by $R_n$... is it just the derivative of the given function with $x$ replaced with $c$?

Comment: What does Theorem $4$ show?

Comment: Alright. A bit of calculating and I should get $R_n(x)$ exactly. Any further explanations in detail would be very much appreciated and accepted.